# Prove that $S_4$ cannot be generated by $(1 3),(1234)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Prove that $S_4$ cannot be generated by $(1 3),(1234)$

I have checked some combinations between $(13),(1234)$ and found out that those combinations cannot generated 3-cycles.

Updated idea:
Let $A=\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$
Note that $(13)A=A,(1234)A=A$
Hence, $\sigma A=A,\forall\sigma\in \langle(13),(1234)\rangle$
In particular, $(12)\notin \sigma A,\forall\sigma\in \langle(13),(1234)\rangle$
So we conclude that $S_4\neq\langle(13),(1234)\rangle$

Comment: In the update, $(1~2)\notin\sigma A$ cannot be right, because $\sigma A$ is a _partition_ of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ (indeed it equals $A$ here), so its elements are subsets, not permutations like $(1~2)$. I think you mean to say $(1~2)A\neq A$ instead. Indeed, $(1~2)A=\{\{2,3\},\{1,4\}\}\neq A$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The partition $\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$ is invariant under the action of the two proposed generators, but not under all of $S_4$, so they cannot generate all of $S_4$.

Comment: Can you explain in a simpler way? I can't get your idea.

Comment: No I cannot explain it in a simpler way. But here is a longer one. The idea is that if one groups together certain elements, there is a "togetherness" relation, and after acting by some permutation, there is a potentially different "togetherness" relation. Here I grouped numbers of equal parity, but if for instance I interchange $1$ with $2$, then it is $\{2,3\}$ and $\{1,4\}$ that become together after the permutation. But it happens that permuting by $(1~3)$ or by $(1~2~3~4)$ one gets the _same_ relation back. Composing the latter two never gives a new relation, so one cannot get $(1~2)$.

Comment: Apply your first permutation: $\{\{3,1\},\{2,4\}\} = \{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$. Apply your second: $\{\{2,4\},\{1,3\}\} =  \{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$. So whatever those two generate fixes that set. But something like $(12) \in S_4$ gives you $\{\{2,3\},\{1,4\}\} \neq \{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$, and so we must not have all of $S_4$. @AlanWang

Comment: Another way to use the same idea: label the corners of a square $1,2,3,4$ in a cycle, then the partition $\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$ describes the diagonals. Both permutations $(1~3)$ and $(1~2~3~4)$ are symmetries of the square, hence preserve the partition into diagonals. But other permutations are not symmetries of the square, and cannot be in the subgroup generated by those two permutations.

Comment: I have updated my idea. Take a look to check whether my proof is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If we denote $a = (1234)$ and $b = (13)$, one can easily check that $a^4 = e$, $b^2 = e$ and $ab = ba^{-1}$ which are precisely relations that define dihedral group $D_4$. Thus, subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ in $S_4$ is isomorphic to quotient of $D_4$, and thus it's order is less or equal than $8$. Since $|S_4| = 4!$, obviously $a$ and $b$ can't generate whole $S_4$. One can easily check that there are $8$ distinct elements in $\langle a,b\rangle$, so it is actually isomorphic to $D_4$.

Answer (score 1):

Here we copy/paste/modify another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3843575/432081):

Define

$\; \tau = (13)$

$\;\sigma = (1234)$


$1^{st} \text {group of calculations:}$

$\;\tau^1 = (13)$

$\;\tau^2 = \tau^0 \quad \text { - the identity permutation}$


$2^{nd} \text{ group of calculations:}$

$\;\sigma^1 = (12)\,(23) \,(34)$

$\;\sigma^2 = (13)\,(24)$

$\;\sigma^3 = (14)\,(24)\,(34)$

$\;\sigma^4 = \sigma^0 \quad \text { - the identity permutation}$


$3^{rd} \text{ group of calculations:}$

$\tau\sigma = (12) \,(34)$

$\tau\sigma^2 = (24)$

$\tau\sigma^3 = (14) \,(23)$


$4^{th} \text{ group of calculations:}$

$\sigma\tau = (14) \,(23)$

$\sigma^2\tau = (24)$

$\sigma^3\tau = (12)\,(34)$



So far we've identified exactly $8$ permutations that are in the group generated by $\tau$ and $\sigma$.

When we run the $4^{th} \text{ group of calculations}$ we get the same permutations as the $3^{rd} \text{ group of calculations}$, and we can now write these symbolic (defining) rules,

$\tag 1 \tau^2 = 1_d$
$\tag 2 \sigma^4 = 1_d$
$\tag 3 \sigma\tau = \tau\sigma^3$

Given any word (string) in the letters $\tau$ and $\sigma$ we can 'move' all the $\tau$ letters to the left and standardize (present/represent) the permutation to have the form

$\tag 4 \tau^n \sigma^m \quad n \in \{0,1\} \text{ and } m \in \{0,1,2,3\}$

We conclude that the group generated by $\tau$ and $\sigma$ has exactly $8$ elements.

Since

$\; \sigma \tau = \tau \sigma^3$

and

$\; \tau \sigma \ne \tau \sigma^3$

we also know that this a non-abelian subgroup of $S_4$.